# What networking packages does Ubuntu use?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, package-management

I feel like Ubuntu comes with a more stable WiFi setup than my manual setup on a different linux distribution. What packages does Ubuntu use for networking and WiFi by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you are concerned about is not related to any userspace package, it's related to the Wi-Fi driver which is built into the kernel, so you should look for the differences between the kernels.

It could also be related to the power management; maybe your other distribution (or some of its packages) is trying to decrease your power usage, so they put your Wi-Fi in "powersaver" mode and thus you experience some instability.

However, Ubuntu comes with `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Addendum: which, like most other solutions, employs `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient` as well as its own built-in code.